# Converting a PPM from RGB to HSL in C__

Tags: c, image-processing, histogram, rgb, ppm

I have some code samples in C. I need to do the histogram equalization. However, I need to forward step by step. I was stucked in first step. First step is to convert the file from RGB to YCbCr.So, I will share the codes with you. All codes that I've is not gonna fit into these area. Also, I've added a picture that shows my failure. I wonder where I'm wrong. I hope somebody can show me the light. The error message says that "pointer value used where a floating point value was expected". What does it mean with this message?

`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<ctype.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <math.h>
#define PI 3.1415926535897932384626433832795
struct ppm_header
{
    char pgmtype1;
    char pgmtype2;
    int pwidth;
    int pheight;
    int pmax;
};
struct ppm_file
{
    struct ppm_header *pheader;
    unsigned char *rdata,*gdata,*bdata;
};

// The codes that I've begin from here.    

/*struct RGB  // In fact, this structer is not a comment. I changed it.
{
    unsigned char R;
    unsigned char G;
    unsigned char B;
};*/

struct YCbCr
{
    float Y;
    float Cb;
    float Cr;
};

struct YCbCr RGBToYCbCr(struct ppm_file rgb) {
    float fr = (float)rgb.rdata / 255;
    float fg = (float)rgb.gdata / 255;
    float fb = (float)rgb.bdata / 255;

    struct YCbCr ycbcr;
    ycbcr.Y = (float)(0.2989 * fr + 0.5866 * fg + 0.1145 * fb);
    ycbcr.Cb = (float)(-0.1687 * fr - 0.3313 * fg + 0.5000 * fb);
    ycbcr.Cr = (float)(0.5000 * fr - 0.4184 * fg - 0.0816 * fb);

    return ycbcr;
}

// The codes that I added end here.

void get_image_data(char *filename,struct ppm_file *image);
void write_image(char *filename,struct ppm_file *image);

// I do not have the enough space for the get_image_data and the write_image functions implementation. 
// If I will a solution for the space, I'll add the functions.

main()
{
    struct ppm_file resim;
    get_image_data("mandrill1.ppm",&resim);


    printf("pgmtype...=%c%c\n",resim.pheader->pgmtype1,resim.pheader->pgmtype2);
    printf("width...=%d\n",resim.pheader->pwidth);
    printf("height...=%d\n",resim.pheader->pheight);
    printf("max gray level...=%d\n",resim.pheader->pmax);

    write_image("pnr.ppm",&resim);
    return 0;
}
```

`

[I've uploaded an image that shows my failures. I hope somebody can help me about that. That warning made me hopeless for the solution.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScjR5.jpg)

Comment: @Piglet you can see my struggles via this post.

Comment: @NominalAnimal  you can see my struggles via this post.

Comment: see that's much better than your terrible last post. still far from [ask] but you are on a good way.

the error message tells you everything. you are using a pointer where the compiler expects a float. it even tells you in which line. you cannot cast an unsigned char pointer to float. please do a c tutorial

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a PPM from RGB to HSL in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43667345/converting-a-ppm-from-rgb-to-hsl-in-c)

Comment: You asked much the same question 2 days before. Don't re-post a question if it was closed! Edit it, addressing the issues given by comments and the close-reason and ask to re-open!

Comment: @Olaf I wanted to delete the previous question Because I did wrong while I prepare my codes.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"The error message says that "pointer value used where a floating point value was expected". What does it mean with this message?"

The message means exactly what it says. You used a pointer value where the compiler expected a floating point value.

According to your definition

```
struct ppm_file
{
    struct ppm_header *pheader;
    unsigned char *rdata,*gdata,*bdata;
};
```

ppm_file.rdata, ppm_file.gdata and ppm_file.bdata are unsigned char pointers.

But you do this:

```
float fr = (float)rgb.rdata / 255;
float fg = (float)rgb.gdata / 255;
float fb = (float)rgb.bdata / 255;
```

so you're trying to cast an unsigned char pointer to float, divide it by 255 and asign that to a float variable. That is not going to work.

First you have to dereference the unsigned char pointer. The resulting unsigned char value can then be cast to a float value, which you can then use as planned.

```
float fr = (float) *rgb.rdata / 255;
```

should do the trick.

Please make sure you have a better understanding of C and it's types befor you continue. There are plenty of good books and tutorials available.

Comment: if you remember my other functions which are the write_image and the get_image_data, then I wanna add a function which uses these structures to convert the file from RGB to YCbCr. Can you help me about that? I mean that I will do some research about that. Still, I need your help about that...... Also, none can be better than you in programming and algorithm skills. PS: I cannot answer my own question. Because I took negative points for previous question. I do not blame you. I blame myself for this. So, I'll wait your answer.

Comment: @raskolnikov: We are not a coding, less a "cheat my class" service! If you want to make it through claas, you have to learn on your own. If you "don't have the time" or don't want to, you better change courses to "knitting for beginners" or something less challenging.